# Could you explain Perron's paradox to me, please?

Tags: infinity, paradoxes

This is [Perron's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oskar_Perron):

> Let $N$ be the largest integer. If $N > 1$, then $N^2 > N$, contradicting the definition of $N$. Hence $N = 1$.

What does it mean? I get from it that a very large number does not exist or $\infty=1$. Am I right? Or maybe the paradox is wrong?

Comment: Maybe a little less rigorous way to look at it is if you say $\infty$ is your biggest number then $\infty^2 = \infty$ and this "proof" breaks down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that *if* there is a largest integer, then that integer is $1$.  That assumption is what led to a silly result.

The point of this "paradox" is to not assume that something exists; the question of whether it exists or not is important to investigate.  It has nothing to do with infinity.

Answer (score 3):

It tells us that we can say anything about a number that does not exist.