# What is wrong with the following proof that one is the largest integer

Tags: proof-verification, fake-proofs

**Note:** that this is not precisely the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648266/what-is-the-flaw-of-this-proof-largest-integer) that has been asked before.

Let $n$ be the largest integer. Then $n>1$. Now $n^2$ is also an integer, and $n^2>n.1=n$. So $n^2>n$. which contradicts $n$ being the largest integer. Therefore our initial assumption is false, and 1 is the largest integer, as claimed.

Comment: I do think it is close enough to count as a duplicate of the other question - the argument is the same, as is the flaw, which is in assuming that any number is the largest positive integer.  There are probably a dozen slightly different ways to write a proof that uses that flow, but I don't think there should be separate questions for all of them.

Comment: There is also this possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861419/could-you-explain-perrons-paradox-to-me-please

Comment: The proof is: "assume that there is an integer $n$ such that ($n$ is the largest integer **and** $n >1$)". Having derived a contradiction, we conclude with the negation: $\forall n \ ( n > 1 \to \exists m \ (n \le m))$ ... that is quite harmless.

Comment: I read the proof slightly differently than @MauroALLEGRANZA did. In my reading, you assumed only that $n$ is the largest integer. You inferred from this (not making a separate assumption but presumably using your knowledge that there is an integer $>1$, like for example 2) that $n>1$. Then you proceeded with the rest of the proof, obtaining a contradiction. So you've proved that your initial assumption, that $n$ is the largest integer, is false. Since $n$ was arbitrary, you have proved that there is no largest integer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the proof *assumes* that there is a largest integer. That assumption is false.